# How do I resolve a whitespace issue in ZyBooks?

Tags: python

I am taking an introductory coding class and am using ZyBooks. I am currently working on a challenge which involves printing a two-dimensional list by row and column. I have mostly worked out the code, except for a persistent whitespace issue. I can't figure out where this extra whitespace is and how to get rid of it

```
user_input= input()
lines = user_input.split(',')


mult_table = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]

for row in mult_table:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        print(row[i],end=" ")
        if i != len(row)-1:
            print('|',end=" ")
    print()
```

ZyBooks is giving me this error:

[image: Error message]

Ending with end="" instead of end=" " results in this error:

2nd Error

[image: 2nd Error]

Thanks!

Comment: Use `end=""` instead of `end=" "` for the last item in the row.

Comment: I tried end="" as well, it also resulted in whitespace errors, albeit different ones. I'll add the screenshot of that error in my original post

Comment: You should ONLY use `end=""` for the last item on the line. You're doing it for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than printing each item and optionally printing the separator after it, print the entire row at once with a single call to `print()`:

```
for row in mult_table:
    print(*row, sep=" | ")
```

`*row` spreads the elements of `row` into separate arguments to `print()`, and `sep=" | "` specifies the separator to use between them instead of just a space.